# Shared a variable between many functions in a DLL in C

Tags: c, dll

Hello (sorry for my bad english).

During my free time, I am doing a little application in python (3.5).

This application will have to call functions from a DLL made in C. I succeed to do it but I have a more "general" question. Let's take an example. I have four functions in my C code :

- goNorth() {y++;}
- goSouth() {y--;}
- goWest()  {x--;}
- goEast()  {x++;}

Easy to understand, just x and y coordinate, each function makes a move. My question is : Is there an easy way (and clean) to share the x and y betwwen all functions if I made a dll of this code ?

Julien

Comment: No clean way, unless that you make the functions part of a class or allow them take an argument, which can be used to access `x` and `y`. An ugly way, would be to introduce the variables as static

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is. Define the variable in an "implementation" file, and declare it as "extern" in a header file:

Implementation file:

```
// mylib.c

#include "mylib.h"

int x;
int y;

void goNorth() { ... }
void goSouth() { ... }
```

Headerfile:

```
// mylib.h

extern int x;
extern int y;

void goNorth();
void goSouth();
```